# Datastax devcenter connection to Azure

Tags: azure, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am using the azure marketplace to deploy the datastax enterprise. Everything seems good, as I can access the opscenter without a problem.

```
http://opscenterxxxxxxxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:8888/opscenter/index.html
```

When I am using the devcenter to connect to the db remotely. The pub ip opscenterxxxxxxxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com cannot go through.

```
The specified host(s) could not be reached.
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: opscenterxxxxxxxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/13.76.96.xx:9042
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got the reply from DataStax that devcenter should connect not connect to the VM hosting opscenter, but running DSE with names like dc0vm0 etc.